# unable to create a Class Diagram in Rational Rhapsody SysML Project

Tags: uml, rhapsody, sysml

I created a Rational Rhapsody project with Project Type set to `SysML`. After creating the project I added `HarmonySE` profile into the project. I also created a `Block Definition Diagram` and a `Requirement Diagram` in the project. But I can't find a way to create a `Class Diagram` in my project. If I click on Tools menu -> Diagrams, Class Diagram is not in the list of diagrams:

[image]

Can someone please suggest how to include `Class Diagram` in a Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Class Diagram in SysML, thus Rhapsody prohibts its usage in a project having the SysML profile. If you want to use class diagrams (i.e., UML in general) for your SW domain, you can add an UML project to your workspace, via File->Add new project. This project can use a different profile, and thus you can create your classical UML diagrams there.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, a *UML* **class** is a **block** in *SysML*. What you are looking for is a *Block Definition Diagram*. There is no Class Diagram in SysML.